# .NET UWP NavigationView.HeaderTemplate TextBlock set from page in Frame

Tags: uwp

I have UWP app with fragment for showing pages in frame. MainPage:

```
    <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="24,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                        Name="tbTitleTextBlock"
                       FontSize="28"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Welcome"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>

    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>
```

How to change text **Welcome** in **tbTitleTextBlock** from page in Frame?
Thanks

Comment: It's not ,clear, but, are you trying to change the header of the `NavigationView` when a page is loaded into the `Frame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change text Welcome in tbTitleTextBlock from page in Frame? Thanks

The `DataContext` of tbTitleTextBlock is same as `NavigationView` header. So you could  use `Text="{Binding}"` to get content of the parent `DataContext`. And when you modify `NavigationView` header property, the tbTitleTextBlock will change automatically.

```
<NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="24,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
            Name="tbTitleTextBlock"
            FontSize="28"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
```

**Usage**

```
 private void NavigationView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
 {
     if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
     {
         contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SampleSettingsPage));
     }
     else
     {
         var selectedItem = (NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem;
         string pageName = "AppUIBasics.SamplePages." + ((string) selectedItem.Tag);
         sender.Header = pageName;
         Type pageType = Type.GetType(pageName);
         contentFrame.Navigate(pageType);
     }
 }
```